# Trigger a Workflow for every item in a list using PowerShell

Tags: list, workflow, powershell, best-practices

What's the best way to go about writing a `PowerShell command` to activate a workflow for each item in a list?

There's a million articles out there and I'm wondering what the best way is.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's the best way, but it will do the trick.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "Url to web";    
$manager = $web.Site.WorkFlowManager;    
$list = $web.Lists["your list"];

$assoc = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("Workflow Name","culture string"); # culture string like en-US

$view = $list.Views["Your view name"]; #All Items

$items = $list.GetItems($view);    
$data = $assoc.AssociationData;

foreach ($item in $items) { $wf = $manager.StartWorkFlow($item,$assoc,$data,$true); }
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I try to run this script: `Get-SPWeb : Cannot find an SPSite object that contains the following Id or Url: http://portaldev.com/sites/it.`

Comment: Try Get-SPWeb Identity ""